# Apply style to the selected mentions in the ANTD mentions component

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to apply style to the selected mentions such that the mentions part looks different from the rest of the normal text.
I am using ANTD framework in my React application and using the mentions component from ANTD as shown below:

```
  <Mentions
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    onChange={onChange}
    onSelect={onSelect}
    defaultValue="@afc163"
    options={[
      {
        value: 'afc163',
        label: 'afc163',
      },
      {
        value: 'zombieJ',
        label: 'zombieJ',
      },
    ]}
  />
```

The scenario is:
User types @ and get list of mentions to select from.
Once the user selects the proper mention its value is shown in the text area with some styling applied to it.

What I tried: I tried applying style to the mentions component but it gets applied to the whole textbox content and not specifically the mentioned part.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using codesandbox